# Как отобразить попап только при первом заходе на страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Нужно отобразить попап только при первом заходе на страницу или при открытии страниц в новых вкладках. Интересуют варианты реализации данного поведения. Jq не помогает. Прошу подсказать или навести на мысль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, в итоге нашёл довольно таки простое решение через window.sessionStorage

```
function showSea() {
  //check the session param
  if (!window.sessionStorage.getItem('done')) {
    ...do-something
    //set the session param
    sessionStorage.setItem('done', 1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для отслеживания первого посещения можно использовать куку.

Для отслеживания других вкладок - web storage.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте куки (JavaScript):

```
if (getCookie('visited') == 1) {
    // повторное посещение
} else {
    // первое посещение
    setCookie('visited', 1);
}
```

Примеров функций ***get/set Cookie*** в сети предостаточно.

Comment: Название нормальное, из него **никак** не следует какой именно сервер используется, поэтому пример с php не подходит ни с какой стороны

Comment: Поправил заголовок

Comment: Самовандалить свой ответ нет нужды. Достаточно было убрать нерелевантную часть.